# Rails 6: skip_before_action for non-symbolic use of before_action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I have an `Auth` module (`auth.rb`), containing a `check_auth` function:

```rb
module Auth
  def check_auth(request)
    # perform authN/authZ based on request information
  end
end
```

Since I need the request, my `ApplicationController` uses this `auth` filter as follows:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Auth
  before_action do |controller|
    check_auth(request)
  end
end
```

I need to skip auth for the `AuthController` (`auth_controller.rb`), of course:

```rb
class Api::V1::Auth::AuthController < ::ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :check_auth, only: [:login]
  def login
    # code to validate credentials and create the token
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, this yields an error:

```
ArgumentError (Before process_action callback :check_auth has not been defined):
  
app/controllers/api/v1/auth/auth_controller.rb:2:in `<class:AuthController>'
app/controllers/api/v1/auth/auth_controller.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Had I used the `check_auth` function symbolically (`ApplicationController`):

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include Auth
  before_action :check_auth
end
```

This error would not occur. However, then the `request` is not passed to my `check_auth` function, which renders it pointless.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skipping before actions only works if they have been set using symbols but this only works if the method has no arguments as you already realised.

In this case, you don't really need arguments, the request object is available everywhere in the controller.

You can either assume the presence of `request` in `module Auth` and remove the argument, or create a new method in your controller:

```
def authenticate
  check_auth(request)
end
```

and then you can call that as a before action.